# Sub or function not defined error on ArcCos

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function in Excel to calculate the distance between two points in latitude longitude.

This function gives me the error

> Compile error:
>
> Sub or function not defined

```
Function DAVIDLATLON(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
 DAVIDLATLON = ArcCos(Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat1)) * Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat2)) + Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat1)) * Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat2)) * Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lon1 - lon2))) * 6371
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the arc-cosine function.  Try:

```
Function DAVIDLATLON(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        DAVIDLATLON = .Acos(Cos(.Radians(90 - lat1)) * Cos(.Radians(90 - lat2)) + Sin(.Radians(90 - lat1)) * Sin(.Radians(90 - lat2)) * Cos(.Radians(lon1 - lon2))) * 6371
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I prefer the use of the WITH

Answer (score 1):

There is no native VBA ArcCos function. Use `worksheetfunction.acos` instead.

```
Function DAVIDLATLON(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
  DAVIDLATLON = WorksheetFunction.Acos(Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat1)) * _
                                       Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat2)) + _
                                       Sin(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat1)) * _
                                       Sin(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - lat2)) * _
                                       Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(lon1 - lon2))) * 6371
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ArcCos Function is not known by VBA my understanding is you could first define the ArcCos function and then reference it from your second function.

```
Function ArcCos(RadAngle)
    ArcCos = Atn(-RadAngle / Sqr(-RadAngle * RadAngle + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1)
End Function

Function DAVIDLATLON(Lat1, Lon1, Lat2, Lon2)
    DAVIDLATLON = ArcCos(Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat1)) * Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat2)) + Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat1)) * Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat2)) * Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Lon1 - Lon2))) * 6371
End Function
```